# Loading Spinner for Webview Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, webview

The following is the code in my ScoreFragment.java that shows a Webview.

```
IMPORT BLAH BLAH
public class ScoreFragment extends Fragment {

public ScoreFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    });


    myWebView.loadUrl("xyz");
   return mainView;
}
}
```

This code is waht i used in my ACtivity for Another different project that also shows Webview  , But this has a Loading spinner that shows up in the left of the action bar:

```
public class Facebook extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);



       mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.MyWebview ); 
       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
       mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       
       mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
       mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/thebanginbeats");

       final Activity MyActivity = this;
       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

           @Override 
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              return false;
            }

           public void onBackPressed (){
               if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();       
                }
                else {
                    //My exit alert code goes here.    
                }
            }

           public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)     {
               handler.proceed() ;
               }

           @Override
           public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);   
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
           }


           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);   
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           }


       } );

}


}
```

Adding the line of code "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);" from the Activity into my Fragment doesn't work. What code would be required to be changed here>?

EDIT : I have changed the code in my fragment to this below. Also the menu.xml is under the menu directory and the item_layout.xml is under the layout directory.
There are no errors except for the line " loading.setVisible(toggle); " which throws and error asking me to set it as Boolean toggle = false;
Any idea as to what is causing it ?

And the line of code " getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()" should it be under onPageFinished ? *Show in code below

```
public class ScoreFragment extends Fragment {

public ScoreFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); //On finishing the page loading
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           }

    });


    myWebView.loadUrl("xyz");
   return mainView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); //This tells the parent activity that the Fragment wants  to add items to the Actionbar
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    //Inflate the menu for this fragment
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    //This is the important part here you can switch the visibility of your menu item
    MenuItem loading = menu.findItem(R.id.progress_bar);

    //Here I use a boolean that is global to my class to set the visibility of the   item.
    loading.setVisible(toggle);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a custom view in you action bar, I mean, make your own progress bar.

Start creating an xml with the view for the progress bar, it can be just like this:

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Then create the menu file:

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Title"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/item_layout">
    </item>    
</menu>
```

As you can see we add the layout file we created as the action (or icon) for the menu item.

Now in your `Fragment` class you need to specify that you want to add something to the `ActionBar`. Just override the `onActivityCreated` method and use `setHasOptionsMenu`

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); //This tells the parent activity that the Fragment wants to add items to the Actionbar
    }
```

Since you are using the `Action Bar`you need to override this two methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        //Inflate the menu for this fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        //This is the important part here you can switch the visibility of your menu item
        MenuItem loading = menu.findItem(R.id.progress_bar);
        //Here I use a boolean that is global to my class to set the visibility of the item.
        loading.setVisible(toggle);
    }
```

Finally whenever you want to change the visibility of the item all you need to do is call

```
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

This method will force the `Action Bar` to recreate and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will be called.
If you change the value of the boolean toggle you will toggle the visibility of the item as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir, I have added the code and created the required menu/layout files. I get an error for the toggle. Can you please check my EDIT in my main post? 
Thank you.

Comment: I see the loading spinner in the action bar, but even when the page has loaded it still continues to load. I believe its due to the toggle that i did not configure correctly.

Comment: Question: Do you need to make the progress bar visible after? If you only want to hide it and don't show it again then you can do `loading.setVisible(false);`. That will do the job

Comment: And yes `invalidateOptionsMenu` it should go under `onPageFinished`